# How to block ip/ports using iptables with specific date and time?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

Normally to block in command-line I used iptables.

```
iptables -I INTPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -m time --utc --datestart 2013-09-09T15:00 --datestop 2013-09-09T15:30 -j DROP
```

But the problem is, this doesn't work in versions greater than iptables v1.4.12
Whereas iptables v1.4.8 works fine with this.

Can somebody tells me what is the change  in recent.

In my embedded linux,

```
# ls -l /sbin/iptables*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sysadmin sysadmin    14 Dec 31  1969 /sbin/iptables -> iptables-multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sysadmin sysadmin 49248 Dec 31  1969 /sbin/iptables-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sysadmin sysadmin    14 Dec 31  1969 /sbin/iptables-restore -> iptables-multi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sysadmin sysadmin    14 Dec 31  1969 /sbin/iptables-save -> iptables-multi
```

In Ubuntu12.04

```
root@user-desktop:~# ll /sbin/iptables*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 18 15:17 /sbin/iptables -> xtables-multi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 18 15:17 /sbin/iptables-restore -> xtables-multi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 18 15:17 /sbin/iptables-save -> xtables-multi*
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work does the command produce an error (and if so what is it) or is it not blocking packets that you think it should?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the spelling error (the first `T` in `INTPUT`) that's causing the problem?

Comment: If the date `Dec 31  1969` is indicative of your clock...